# Dynamic pthread spawning sync required(???)

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to write some code using posix threads but I'm stuck from the first step and to be honest I can't realise why. I know that my problem has probably to do with some sort of synchronisation but I can't figure it out.

What I have in main is the following:

```
while(1){
  int x = getX();
  pthread_t t;
  printf("Main: %d\n",x);
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, process_x, &x);
}
```

When I try to print the x value from the main and also the process_x function what I get is something like this:

> Main: 1
>
> Main: 2
>
> Main: 3
>
> Main: 4
>
> Main: 5
>
> Process_x: 5

What do I miss here?

---- EDIT -----

OK, maybe I need to provide some more info. The getX function receives data from a socket and returns an identifier while for our needs now the process_x just prints the argument it receives.

Comment: You are very familiar with the problem and your code, but we are not. Will you please give some more explanation and post the code? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Where is your `Main: %d` print??

Comment: So I assume something is not right about what is printed. What is wrong? What did you 'expect' it to print?

Comment: I expected it to print something like:

> Main: 1

> Process_x : 1

> Main : 2

> Process_x : 2

> etc.

Comment: Process_x: 5 was printed only once? Did you try running your program multiple times?

Comment: No it was printed multiple times actually. Yes I tried to run it multiple times.

E.g. I suck at describing my problem apparently.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I managed to make it work thanks to all your ideas. The think is with malloc that it also sets the x value to zero so it doesn't work. Anyway what I did was to use a conditional_variable to signal the main when the x value was copied to a local value inside process_x. I will post the code with the answer later because right now the site doesn't let me (need to wait a few hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently using malloc doesn't work because it sets x to 0 so the process always reads 0. But thanks to everyones ideas I finally made it work using a condition variable and now everything is ok. Here is the code.

```
int main{
  pthread_t t;
  int x;
  while(1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&receive);
    x = getX();
    printf("Main: %d\n",x);
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, process_x, &x);
    pthread_cond_wait(&goOn, &receive);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&receive);
  }
}

void *process_x(void* arg){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&receive);
  int x = *(int *) arg;
  pthread_cond_signal(&goOn);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&receive);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider that you pass the address of `x` to a thread, and then without waiting for the thread to finish printing, you modify it's value. Obviously, this will mean that if a few iterations are over before the thread gets to print it's value, the value would have changed.

Two Ways around this:

1) Use a [`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) and wait for the thread to finish. This is esseentially useless. Because then what is the point of spawning the new thread?

OR

2) Allocate a new address for each thread, and let the thread free it after it finishes printing.

i.e. `malloc` a new integer, assign `x` to that integer, pass the new `malloc`d integer to the thread, let the thread `free` it when done.

Comment: About the first of all: Yeah you are right, I already do that but I did a typo here.

About the memory changing you are probably right. Will try it out now.

Comment: An array would be easier than mallocing every time. Isn't it?

Comment: He is doing a `while(1)` infinite loop, so probably not. We don't even know how wide the array should be.

Answer (score 0):

**A thread will not be executed as soon as you create it** using a call to `pthread_create`. The scheduler can decide to keep it in queue. During that time your `while` loop has run 5 times and value of `x` might also have changed to 5. Now when your thread(s) is(are) eventually scheduled, it(they) only sees the latest value of your `x` and hence print(s) only 5.

I strongly suspect that `Process_x` was printed only once?

There is no default way to get pthreads executed in any specific order. You need to use some synchrnization techniques like semaphores. Also if you want to see `Process_x` print all your values, convert `x` into an array and pass `x[i]` as argument to `pthread_create`

Comment: My problem was not actually to print the messages in the correct order. I know that in order to do that I need to use mutexes and singals between the threads. I just wanted all the threads to be processed

Comment: If you change `x` into an array as I suggested, all threads should execute and display proper values, though not in order, as you already know

Comment: @gkaran89 You're passing a pointer to X to your thread. The next iteration of your loop you change that X, and bad things happen. You could dynamically allocate X every time, so each thread gets their unique value